# Random walk on the integers

Tags: probability, random-walk

A particle initially stands at $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Every second, it jumps one unit towards $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each.

What is the probability that it reaches $+1$?

Answer (score 4):

The probability to hit $1$ after $1$ step is $\frac{1}{2}$, encoded by the string $+$; the probability to hit $1$ after $3$ steps is $\frac{1}{8}$, encoded by the string $-++$; the probability to hit $1$ after $5$ steps is $\frac{1}{16}$, encoded by the strings $-+-++$ and $--+++$. To compute the probability to hit $1$ after $2k+1$ steps, we just have to count how many binary strings of length $2k$, with $k$ zeroes and $k$ ones, have more zeroes than ones in every prefix. This is a well-known problem: the solution is given by the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):
$$ C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}. $$
The probability to hit $1$ in the first $2N+1$ steps is so:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}(k+1)}\binom{2k}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}-\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}\right)\\=1-\frac{1}{4^{N+1}}\binom{2N+2}{N+1}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(N+5/4)}}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^{5/2}}\right).$$

Comment: after 3 steps it is 3/8 since you have -++ and +-+ and ++-, no?

Comment: @Eric: +-+ hits one at the first step, as well as ++-

Comment: right, stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are allowed to wait forever: 1.

There are lots of ways to do this. Suppose we ask the question hit 1 or -n first and stop when this happens.

Then since hitting time is a finite stopping time, the value of the random walk stopped at the hitting is still a martingale and so has expectation 0. So probability of hitting $1$ is $n$ times that of hitting $-n.$ So the probability of hitting $1$, is $n/(n+1).$

The probability you want must be bigger than this for any $n$ so it must be $1.$

Comment: You would also have to show that the probablilty of hitting $1$ or $-n$ is $1$ for each $n$.

Comment: @JiK And this is a fairly easy exercise with the generator, since we can consider the problem $Au=-1,u(1)=u(-n)=0$, whose solution is $u(x) = E(\tau | X_0 = x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\, P_{\sigma} = \half}$ is the probability of taking a jump of length $\ds{\sigma\ =\ \pm 1}$. So, the desired answer is given by:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{\sigma_{1}\ =\ \pm}\sum_{\sigma_{2}\ =\ \pm}\ldots\sum_{\sigma_{N}\ =\ \pm} \, P_{\sigma_{1}}\, P_{\sigma_{2}}\ldots \, P_{\sigma_{N}}
\delta_{\sigma_{1} + \sigma_{2}+\cdots+\sigma_{N},1}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{\sigma_{1}\ =\ \pm}\sum_{\sigma_{2}\ =\ \pm}\ldots\sum_{\sigma_{N}\ =\ \pm} \, P_{\sigma_{1}}\, P_{\sigma_{2}}\ldots \, P_{\sigma_{N}}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z^{\sigma_{1} + \sigma_{2} + \cdots + \sigma_{N}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
\pars{\sum_{\sigma\ =\ \pm}P_{\sigma}z^{-\sigma}}^{N}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
\pars{\half\, z + \half\,{1 \over z}}^{N}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{N}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{N} \over z^{N}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
={1 \over 2^{N}}\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose \ell}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z^{N - 2\ell}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{N}}\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose \ell}\delta_{2\ell,N - 1}
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 2^{N}}\,{N \choose \bracks{N - 1}/2}}
\quad\dsc{{\tt\mbox{if}}\ N\ {\tt\mbox{is odd and}}\ N \geq 1}.
\\&\dsc{\mbox{Otherwise, it vanishes out}}.
\end{align}

[image]